Первая игра на js
Всем привет, хочу вкатиться в разработку игр (до этого написал много ботов).
Собрался сделать mini app в тг - игру кликер. Накидал в фигме интерфейс, а что делать с js вообще не понимаю, ибо никогда с этим не работал.
Суть игры в том, что при нажатии по экрану корабль стреляет лазером по монеткам - при попадании монетка пропадает, а счетчик увеличивается на единицу. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чего вообще начать изучение информации, какие инструменты использовать

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

если не работали с js и html5, то надо хотя бы почитать про это и попробовать попрограммировать/сверстать что-нибудь, чтобы въехать в процесс. А после этого начать вчитываться вот в это https://grammy.dev/guide/games

и далее, вот https://core.telegram.org/bots/games

Для реализации подобных решений можно посмотреть в сторону Phaser.js или Pixi.js. Это библиотеки для упрощённой работы с webGL. На сайтах библиотек есть много примеров реализации разных механик.

ответ ссылка -> подлежит удалению. Расширьте ваш ответ, включите краткое описание возможностей  библиотек, различия, плюсы\минусы(ограничения) использования

@Dmitry нормальный ответ на поставленный вопрос. Просили инструменты - вот они по именам )
